# Can one verify the Earth tide in his yard?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, geophysics, tidal-effect

The ocean tide you can see on the coast. But the Earth tide beneath our feet is hardly perceivable. Is there any way to verify it in one's yard?

Comment: Sure. How much money do you have for a precision GPS? There are a couple of webpages which claim that a regular GPS can also be used with cm resolution, which could actually work. http://hackaday.com/2013/08/05/centimeter-level-precision-gps-for-500/

Comment: Or a high-precision gravitometer might work.

Comment: As @Curious says, a fixed, integrating GPS station can achieve better than 20 cm resolution, so you ought to be able to pick the approximately diurnal variation out of the observations. The signal will be buried in a fairly noisy background, but it should be there.

Comment: Are you asking about measuring the distortion of the Earth's crust under the influence of the moon (and sun), or about the variations in $g$ at a given point? These are different things, and require different approaches.